# Using Python Selenium Webdriver to open Electron Application

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, electron, selenium-chromedriver

I've been attempting to bypass using Spectron for End2End testing an electron application by leveraging my experience with Selenium Webdriver on Python.
Using a combination of the [Chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started) get started page, and several [resources](http://bigdatadummy.blogspot.com/2015/05/using-selenium-testing-for-electron.html) that seem to suggest its possible, this is what I came up with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.chrome.service as service
servicer = service.Service('C:\\browserDrivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')
servicer.start()
capabilities = {'chrome.binary': 'C:\\path\\to\\electron.exe'}
remote = webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver(command_executor=servicer.service_url, desired_capabilities = capabilities, browser_profile=None, proxy=None, keep_alive=False
```

The issue is that instead of opening the electron application, it opens a standard instance of Chrome.

Most of resources I've seen have been several years old so something may have changed to make it no longer possible.

Does anyone know of a way to use Python Selenium WebDriver to test an Electron application?

Comment: I think this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72447964/testing-electron-application-with-selenium-python-robotframework

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below works great for me

```
from selenium import webdriver


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "/Applications/Electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get("http://www.google.com")


driver.quit()
```

Comment: Clearly I way over complicated it. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know why this does not work when I try to launch atom or gitkraken (which are electron apps)?